# How to alter the execution of delegate methods in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my  didselectrowatindexpath method:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView==self.tableView1) {
        UITableViewCell * Cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.btnoutlet1 setTitle:Cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.tableView1.hidden = YES;
        _projdict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_projdict setObject:[self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]   forKey:@"beta"];
        NSLog(@" %@",_projdict);
        _projid = [[_projdict objectForKey:@"beta"] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@ " %@" , _projid);
    }
}
```

From this i get projid as 'x'.

Then I want to execute this method and values have to be pass through this.

```
- (void) issuedetais  {
    NSLog(@ " %@" , _projid);
    NSString * project_id1 =[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"Project_id=%@",projid];
    NSLog(@"%@",project_id1);
    NSString * u1 =@“xxx/issues.json?";
    NSString * u2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",u1,project_id1];
    NSLog(@"%@",u2);
}
```

I want url  like this:

```
u2=xxx/issues.json?Project_id=8
```

In viewdidload I calls like this:

```
- (void) viewdidload {
    [self projectdetails];
    [self issuedetails];
    [self activitydetails];
    [self Toformjsondata];
}
```

1. During Runtime,method issue details executes first so the projid is null.
2. Instead of that didselectrowatindexpath executes first i will get the projid.
3. I want to execution of hierarchy of method will be like this

   1. void project details
   2. didselectrowatindexpath
   3. issuedetails.

or else how to do hierarchy of execution of methods.or any other way to do this?any other alternate to do this?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. If you to call `issuedetails` when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, then why don't you just call it from `didSelectRowAtindexPath`, itself. If you don't want to call `issuedetails` from `viewDidLoad`, then don't. I must not be understanding what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can step back, edit your question, and clearly describe what you're trying to functionally accomplish. (BTW, make sure `viewDidLoad` calls `super`.)

Comment: sir if i run the app.... void (issuedetails)put a logger in nslog(@"%@",projid) it shows null...sir...so i think initially that method is called first....but i get the value form didrowselectatindexpath...nslog(projid) i have to pass this value to method issuedetails....for foramtion f url..above metioned...sir...you said why don't you call it from didselectrowatindexpath...how to do that one sir?

Comment: Add a line in `didSekectRowAtIndexPath` that says `[self issuedetails]`.

Comment: Please don't pester people to look at other questions

Comment: @Rob sir please take a look at this question and suggest me ideas sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576293/fix-bug-date-values-work-in-iphone-but-not-ipad

Comment: As Flexo said, please stop posting comments to ask people to look at other questions.

Comment: @Rob k sir, sorry for that....here after i won't do this....