# Fix bug: Date values work in iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, logging

In my app,I have to display the date values for a week.It works fine on iPhone but not in iPad.

1.This image shows the date values(21...27) above the text box in iPhone

[image]

2.This image shows the erroneous date values(3) above the text box in iPad.

[image]

For this My piece of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// here the self.startday value has been passed from one controller to another.
_datelabel.text = self.startday;
// here the self.startday =@"2016-02-23"
[self method1];
[self getdateArray];
[self method2];
}
```

My piece of code for method get date:

```
-(void) get date
{
NSString *dateStr,*strday;
NSString *dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:dateFormat];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:self.startday];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;
NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatters setDateFormat:dateFormat];
[dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
dateStr = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
self.wkDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.wkDayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
for(int i =0 ;i<7;i++)
{
NSDate *newdate = [destinationDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*i];
NSDateComponents *comp =[calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:newdate];
strday =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[comp day]];
[self.wkDayArray insertObject:strday atIndex:i];
dateStr = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: newdate];
[self.wkDateArray insertObject:dateStr atIndex:i];
}
NSLog(@"%@",self.wkDayArray[0]);
NSLog(@"%@",self.wkDateArray[0]);
}
```

// Logger for this line:

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:self.startday];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

If I put logger for "date" in "iPhone destination" output will be:

```
iphone:2016-02-20 18:30:00 +0000
```

If I put logger for date in "iPad destination" output will be:

```
ipad:(null)
```

Then I conclude that because of this null value,some erroneous value has been sets.

Why it shows null value in iPad destination?what's the exact solution for this?Thanks in advance.Please help me out.

Comment: iPAd simulator give same output ?

Comment: has the iPad the same timezone/location ?

Comment: first image is the iPhone output,second image is the iPad output.

Comment: @JonasSchafft i have to check sir...

Comment: @DipenChudasama bro i edited my question,please take a look.give me suggestions

Comment: @JonasSchafft sir i edited my question,please take a look.

Comment: Did you check the timezone in your ipad settings? Is this a simulator or real ipad? Real iphone or simulator? Can you provide a little sample application?

Comment: it's a simulator sir...

Comment: if it's simulator then how to check the time zone settings sir?

Comment: i tried your code. Everything works fine. I post an answer with steps you should try.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new universal App for iPad and iPhone and only change this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *startday = @"2016-02-23";
    NSString *dateStr,*strday;
    NSString *dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:startday];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);

}
```

And then tell me if it works on both devices.